# Use of JAVA EE 7 when only RESTful application needed as backend for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, jakarta-ee

I'm building a RESTful application to serve as the back end for an ANGULARJS front end application. I would like to use java for the backend component and hence looked into JAVA EE 7, which seem to do the job, but I do not intend to use JPA or any other JAVA EE technologies except maybe JSON processing.

So my question is: is it still worth it to go with JAVA EE and use EJB as resources knowing I'll be getting the overhead of a EJB container and the general weight of JAVA EE server, or use JAVA SE + JERSEY ? Is that actually an alternative?

Thanks
Ibrahim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAX-RS is part of the JEE specification so its not really an option to just use Java-SE.  So what you really looking for is a lightweight solution to still host a JAX-RS application.  You do not need to use a full JEE container to accomplish this if you do not plan to use the full stack.  You can use Tomcat for example.  There are a few examples on how to use Tomcat and a JAX-RS implementation like Jersey or RestEasy:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/restful-web-services-with-resteasy-jax.html

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-tomcat/

If your company has cash you can always look at the evil empire IBM and their Liberty Profile but I would say stick to Tomcat :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Jersey is part of JavaEE stack. The thing is, JavaEE is modular, You can use just what you really need (in this case, Jersey, which is a reference implementation for JAX-RS 2.0 specification). Have a look at great community examples regarding JAX-RS on [GitHub](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/jaxrs) that were inspired by Arun Gupta. This might help You with Your decision

Comment: Great examples. Thanks a lot